# Why JSON indexing take less storage than multiple columns in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, index, json, mysql-8.0, storage

I am doing a quick performance comparison for **10 000 rows** on **MySQL 8.0.27** between

- a table `multiple_cols` with 2 columns `num INT` and `str CHAR(200)` having each an index,
- a table `json_indexing` with 1 column `content JSON` and 2 JSON indexes.

Can you explain why `json_indexing` table is 3 times smaller than `multiple_cols`?

```
+---------------+------------+
| Table         | Size in MB |
+---------------+------------+
| json_indexing |       2.05 |
| multiple_cols |       6.36 |
+---------------+------------+

// ^results generated with the query:
SELECT 
    table_name AS `Table`, 
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_name in ('multiple_cols', 'json_indexing') ;
```

Below are the creation/insertion queries if it can help:

```
CREATE TABLE json_indexing
(
    content JSON
    , INDEX json_indexing_content_num_idx ((JSON_VALUE(content, '$.num' RETURNING SIGNED)))
    , INDEX json_indexing_content_str_idx ((JSON_VALUE(content, '$.str' RETURNING CHAR(200))))
);

INSERT INTO json_indexing (content)
VALUES ('{ "num": 1, "str": "1" }'), ('{ "num": 2, "str": "2" }') /* ... */ ;

CREATE TABLE multiple_cols
(
    num INT
    , str CHAR(200)
    , INDEX multiple_cols_num_idx (num)
    , INDEX multiple_cols_str_idx (str)
);

INSERT INTO multiple_cols (num, str) VALUES (1, '1'), , (2, '2') /* ... */;
```

Notice that the JSON index for `num` returns `SIGNED` because it does not accept `INT`. That is beyond my understanding for now.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Change that `CHAR` to `VARCHAR` and see if the ordinary indexes shrink.

Comment: @RickJames that was it, thank! But I am still curious ... `data_length` is now equals for both tables, but `index_length` is 2.03MB for `json_indexing` and 1.03MB for `index_columns`. I would have expected the other way around: the indexes size should be equals for both tables, and the data size should be bigger for the JSON! Any idea why?

Comment: Glad `VARCHAR helped.  I don't yet understand the details of JSON indexing, so I can't explain your observation.